# Flask: How can I add a table with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, flask, datatables

So I recently started building my first flask app. Unfortunatly I've hit a wall.
I want to add a pandas dataframe table with `df.to_html` but I've can visit the page with the table.

right now i've got my code setup like this:

My CSV file looks like this:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mr. John Bradley",male,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
```

The app.py code

```
    @app.route('/')
    def base():
        return render_template('/base.html')

    @app.route('/index')
    def index():
        data = pd.read_csv("data/mydata.csv", sep='\s+', quotechar=',')
        data.set_index(['Name'], inplace=True)
        data.index.name=None
        df = data.loc[data.Sex=='male']
        return render_template('/index.html',tables=[df.to_html('male')], titles = ['na', 'males'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The HTML code:
This is the Base-template (route goes to /base aswell)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <a href="{{ url_for('base') }}">Home</a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Index</a>
  </div>
      <div class="content">
         <p>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>.</p>
  </div>
</body>
      {% block body %}
      {% endblock %}
```

The Index HTML code looks like this

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="1">
                <div class=page>
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                    {% for table in tables %}
                        <h2>{{titles[loop.index]}}</h2>
                        {{ table|safe }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

unfortunately I get an Error if I go to the Index page.
The base.html page works just fine.

Error message is (404 Not Found):

*Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.*

Is it possible to add a pandas dataframe or is it not even possible with Flask?

Comment: If the problem was with the execution of your code, such as exception being raised, you would have most likely gotten a 500.  A 400 indicates that you did not set up your routing correctly.  Is there something special about index and index.html?  Have you tried renaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

panda work with flask its not an issue..
This is the syntax what i used and it works fine... 
render_template('index.html') without slash and template is in 'templates' folder

```
def index():
    data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    data.set_index(['Name'], inplace=True)
    data.index.name=None

    df = data.loc[data.Sex=='male']
    df = df[['Sex']]
    return render_template('index.html',tables=[df.to_html(header=False)],titles=['na','Males'])
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work. I use Pycharm to make python and Flask run. could that be the issue?

Comment: could you add your html code for the page aswell? I think the problem might be in there

Comment: Well i am not sure about that as your base url works so flask is working...you can try to specify port ?
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000) #run app in debug mode on port 5000`

Comment: Fixed it. it turns out that my index.html is/was bugged

Comment: great its fixed.